# HTTP POST and GET with cookies for authentication in python

Tags: python, http, authentication, post, cookies

I'm trying to create a python program that logs in to my university's site using my id and password. This is the formal page for logging in: https://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/

As you may notice, the two fields are named pr1 and pr2. The page uses POST to send the data. ALSO, there's a cookie that is downloaded when the page is loaded, it's a JSESSIONID containing a random value that, as I understood, you have to return on the header of the POST method to authenticate the login.

I wrote the following code, but the return page on the GET method says "The session was not initialized", probably cause the cookie was not sent back properly.

```
from urllib2 import Request, build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler
import httplib, urllib, cookielib, Cookie, os

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('webapp.pucrs.br')

#COOKIE FINDER
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),HTTPHandler())
req = Request('http://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/principal.jsp')
f = opener.open(req)
html = f.read()
for cookie in cj:
    c = cookie
#FIM COOKIE FINDER

params = urllib.urlencode ({'pr1':111049631, 'pr2':<pass>})
headers = {"Content-type":"text/html",
           "Set-Cookie" : "JSESSIONID=70E78D6970373C07A81302C7CF800349"}
            # I couldn't set the value automaticaly here, the cookie object can't be converted to string, so I change this value on every session to the new cookie's value. Any solutions?

conn.request ("POST", "/consulta/servlet/consulta.aluno.ValidaAluno",params, headers) # Validation page
resp = conn.getresponse()

temp = conn.request("GET","/consulta/servlet/consulta.aluno.Publicacoes") # desired content page
resp = conn.getresponse()

print resp.read()
```

Where do I put this cookie so the login is authenticated?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would try using the `requests` library. The [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is excellent, and the code ends up being much cleaner than with `urllib*`

```
$ pip install requests
```

Using a [session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) (see comment by Piotr) that handles cookies on its own, the result looks like this

```
import requests
url_0 = "http://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/principal.jsp"
url = "https://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/servlet/consulta.aluno.ValidaAluno"
data = {"pr1": "123456789", "pr2": "1234"}

s = requests.session()
s.get(url_0)
r = s.post(url, data)
```

It seems to work fine, as I get a "Usuario inexistente" notice for `pr1` 123456789 and "Sehna inválida" with your user-number.

Comment: You can use session to handle cookies automatically. From [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects): The *Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance.*

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost That's cool, thank you! And the code looks even better.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the same "opener" you have created for all your requests, and it will handle the cookies all by itself.

here is an extract of something i wrote recently

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))

# then for all requests

if postData:     
    pData =  urllib.urlencode(postData)
else:
    pData = None

httpReq = urllib2.Request(url, pData, self._headers)
page =  opener.open(httpReq)
```

Answer (score 5):

Converting MatthieuW's Answer to Python 3 gives.

```
import urllib, http.cookiejar

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(http.cookiejar.CookieJar()))
# then for all requests

if postData:     
    pData =  urllib.parse.urlencode(postData)
else:
    pData = None

httpReq = urllib.request.Request(url, pData)
page =  opener.open(httpReq)
```

Answer (score 3):

urllib is no good, use requests!

```
from requests import Request, Session

url = "https://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/principal.jsp"
s = requests.Session()

p = dict(pb1 = 'dd', pb2 = 'cc')
r = s.get(url, params = p) 
# use the cert=/path/to/certificate.pem if you need it
# elsewhere use verify = False to bypass ssl verification

c = r.cookies

# Then send back a response using those same cookies

r = requests.get(other_url, cookies = c, verify = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), it automatically handles sessions/cookies/logins for you, furthermore it provides a urllib-like API and e.g. form-filling, so you don't have to mess with the right POST-request, since it gets constructed by mechanize.

Comment: I installed it but it keeps saying there's no installed module called mechanize. Kind of weird, but I'll keep trying. It also handles the cookies? Cause that's my only problem.

Comment: Yes it handles the cookies! Maybe you installed it for the wrong Python version.