# When using the requests library to authenticate, where are the responses stored?

Tags: python, http, authentication, post, python-requests

I am trying to test user credentials on a web application that uses POST forms, using the `requests` library for `Python`. When my test fails (using the wrong password for a username), I want to capture the error message from the application. Problem is, I can't find the object's attribute where this is stored.

Have been using the answer found in [HTTP POST and GET with cookies for authentication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247054/http-post-and-get-with-cookies-for-authentication-in-python/10248314#10248314). They mention the replies received from the web application, to confirm if credentials worked or not, but no reference to the attributes.

I used their Python code but cant find the replies in any of the attributes:

```
>>> r.__dict__.keys()
>>> ['cookies', '_content', 'headers', 'url', 'status_code', '_content_consumed', 'encoding', 'request', 'raw', 'error', 'config', 'history']
```

Any pointers? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) for the `requests` module? (hint: `r.text`)

(It's not in `r.__dict__` because it is not an attribute of the instance. It's a property and is therefore stored on the class.  `dir(r)` would have found it, though.)

Comment: Thanks kindall, using `dir()` was very helpful, as well as `r.text`. I was also missing a parameter to have the `post` method work, leaving out `'submit': 'Login'`.