# Using Python to login webpage (cookies GET and POST involved)

Tags: python, http, cookies, authentication

I am trying to use Python 2.7.6 to login a website. the login logic contains 2 steps in 2 webpages.

1. Putting in user ID and password onto page A, and the page A gives a cookie;
2. This cookie is used in the header to authenticate the login on page B.

It only logs in successfully once B authenticated it.

There’s a post here, [HTTP POST and GET with cookies for authentication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247054/http-post-and-get-with-cookies-for-authentication-in-python), asking the similar question. A solution is using requests.

```
import requests
url_0 = "http://www.PAGE_A.com/" # http://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/principal.jsp, in original example
url = "http://www.PAGE_B.com/" # https://webapp.pucrs.br/consulta/servlet/consulta.aluno.ValidaAluno, in original example
data = {"field1_username": "ABC", " field_password": "123"}

s = requests.session()
s.get(url_0)
r = s.post(url, data)
```

I tired used this in Python for my case and it doesn't return error message so I guess it works fine.

But the question is, how do I know it’s logged in?

I added below to print the logged in page to see if it returned the right page.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
open_page = br.open("http://www.PAGE_B.com/")
read_page = open_page.read()

print read_page
```

However, it stills shows the contents before login. What went wrong?

Comment: You seem to be creating a new session when you execute your second part of the program?

Comment: thanks PCoder for the comment. I had no idea how to verify if I successfully login, by the first part of the script. So I added the 2nd part. What would be a good way to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just going with one of the two?

```
import mechanize;

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.addheaders = [('...')]

browser.open(YOUR_URL)
browser.select_form(FORM_NAME)
browser.form['USERNAME_FIELD'] = 'abc'
browser.form['PASSWORD_FIELD'] = 'password'
browser.submit()
print browser.response().read()
print browser.geturl()
```

Comment: thanks PCoder. but it returns "httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error"

Comment: Well you need to debug. Try to see what are the exact headers passed when done in a real browser (eg. firefox), and then try to replicate using mechanize. `500: Internal Server Error` indicates that the server could not handle your request.