# Python - Login to site and post

Tags: python, html, authentication

I will login to site and post to shoutbox.php. I try this :

```
import urllib
import urllib2
login_data=urllib.urlencode({'username':'daniixxl','password':'steaua','submit':'Login'}) # replace username and password with filed name 
op = urllib.urlopen('http://myxz.org/takelogin.php',login_data)
print op.read(100)
url = 'http://myxz.org/shoutbox.php'
data = urllib.urlencode({'shbox_text' : 'joe',
                         'sent'  : 'yes'})
req2 = urllib2.Request(url, login_data)

print data
```

Problem is: Not post to shoutbox.php

Comment: after you send request, server send response to you - check what you get. Maybe you get HTML with error message or other information. To login on most servers you have to use cookies - sending second request without cookies doesn't inform server that you are already login. Better use `requests` module and `requests.Session()`.

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247054/http-post-and-get-with-cookies-for-authentication-in-python/10248432#10248432   use a "build_opener" to ensure session cookies are kept.

Comment: @furas  You don't need an external lib to handle cookies smoothly.

Comment: @ch7kor yes, I know. But `requests` makes life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from requests import session




mesaj_postat = {'yupii iar'}
logare = { 'username':'daniixxl',
           'password':'steaua'
           }

with session() as sesiune:
                    resp = sesiune.post('http://myxz.org/takelogin.php',data=logare)
                    if "statusdetails" in resp.text:
                        print("Logare reusita")
                    else:
                        print("Logare nereusita")
```