# Automatically log onto Bloomberg through API Python

Tags: python, api, bloomberg

Is there any way to automatically log on through the Bloomberg API to fetch data? From my testing with Python the API can pull data when I am logged into Bloomberg through the terminal and some time after I log off.

The next morning I try to run my code with an error, but the problem goes away as soon as I log on the terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. How does the API actually work? Few people might be using this specific API, so giving us more details might enable more people to answer it. My *guess* is that you need to get a cookie from the Bloomberg server. If you can post your code we'll be able to help. As for getting cookies with Python, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247054/http-post-and-get-with-cookies-for-authentication-in-python

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke A Bloomberg terminal doesn't use cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to log in to be able to run the API. Once you log off, you can still pull data as long as you don't log onto a different computer. That's by design.

So there is no other solution than either manually logging onto your terminal in the morning or making sure that you don't use Bloomberg Anywhere on another PC.